# Adjacent sibling selectors not working in Mozilla Firefox 39.0.3

Tags: html, css, firefox, selector, mozilla

I have this code: 
HTML:

```
<label>
    <input class="checkable" type="checkbox"  value="6" name="Peak">
    <button class="button">1</button>
</label>
<label>
    <input class="checkable" type="checkbox" value="12" name="Peak">
    <button class="button">2</button>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label > .checkable{
    display:none;
}
label > .checkable + button{ 
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:1px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border:transparent;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;background: rgba(0,0,0,0);

}
label > .checkable:checked + button{ 
    background-color:#690b0c;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
```

I am combining a checkbox with a  element. When you click on one of these buttons they should get a red round background. This works as expected in IE 11 but in the newest version of Firefox there seem to be some problems.
Does Anyone have a workaround on this?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jjqg5apa/

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Chrome either.

Comment: It did work in Firefox 37.

Comment: Hmm...it's not the selector...it works if the `display:none` is removed.

Comment: it even works with `opacity:0` but the elements do not "combine" properly in this case.

Comment: I reported it to Bugzilla, see the reply from Tooru Fujisawa: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1197770

Comment: I'd suggest you post that as an answer (you're allowed). That sort of information is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reply from Tooru Fujisawa:

---

This won't be a spec issue nor a Firefox's bug.

I believe Firefox 38+'s behavior matches to what the spec says.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element:the-label-element-10

> The activation behaviour of a label element for events targeted at
>   interactive content descendants of a label element, and any descendants of
>   those interactive content descendants, must be to do nothing.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content-2

> Interactive content is content that is specifically intended for user interaction.
>     a, audio (if the controls attribute is present), button, ...

When you click a button inside a label, the label's activation behavior must be "to do nothing" because the button is an interactive content, it means that we should think that user want to activate the button, instead of the enclosing label, so it won't change the checkbox's state by clicking the button.

I think you could use non-interactive content instead of the button (not sure if it's good for a11y tho), or just unhide the checkbox and use it instead of the button.

---

see full bug report: bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1197770